# can't call C++ function from C#

Tags: c#, c++, function, dll, import

I have a DLL with a set of functions. The DLL was used with "themidia" to make it safe.

When I try to call the functions, C# spits out errors due to the functions names.

```
[DllImport("safety.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall, ExactSpelling=true)]
private static extern IntPtr _encryptLogin@8(string string_0, string string_1);
```

If I remove the @8 and remove ExactSpelling=true, it just returns an exception saying no entry point.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with "Themida" but it could very well be that the process changed the way your methods are exported from the DLL. Try to open `safety.dll` with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and look for the method's real name. This could also be a mismatch with the Calling Conventions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [themidia virtual C++ DLL functions can not be called due to @ in name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549735/themidia-virtual-c-dll-functions-can-not-be-called-due-to-in-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the "@", and in your attribute add `EntryPoint="_encryptLogin@8"`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to specifying `EntryPoint` as rfmodulator suggested, you can use [`extern "C"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d.aspx) in your C++ source, which will make the exported function names the same as their names in your C++ source.

C++ compiler normally mangles the names of functions, so that you can have overloaded functions (functions with the same name bu different parameters).